# How to determine which document sphinx is working on?

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm working on a large documentation base and adding another file of documentation about a programmatically-generated API.  I want to autodoc the contents of a couple modules, but only the functions that have had an attribute set to indicate they are API endpoints.  Autodoc is also used for documenting the internals of the project.

I'm doing this in conf.py:

```
def skip_non_api_methods(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    if not getattr(obj, 'is_api_endpoint', False):
        return True
    return skip

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-skip-member", skip_non_api_methods)
```

However, I only want skip_non_api_methods() to be used for **api.rst**, not the several dozen other documentation files.  I dug into the app object but couldn't find a reference to the current file being processed.

Answer (score 1):

app.env.docname contains the current document name, minus the extension.

A revised version of the function above makes it only work for 'api.rst':

```
def skip_non_api_methods(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    if app.env.docname != 'api':  # only apply this to api.rst
        return skip
    # if is_api_endpoint is True, don't skip (i.e. return False)
    is_api_endpoint = getattr(obj, 'is_api_endpoint', False)
    if is_api_endpoint:
        return False  # don't skip api endpoints
    return True  # skip everything else
```